# Understand Systemd basic.target after boot time

Tags: systemd

The question I have here is to understand `basic.target` upon booting my CentOS 7 server.

A few things I think I know correctly about Systemd:

- `Requires=unit2` means some `unit1` will only be activated if `unit2` succeeds all the way
- `Wants=unit2` means some `unit1` will be activated regardless whether
  the listed unit2 succeeds or not
- `After=unit2` means some `unit1` will only be activated after unit2 is activated
- Things in Systemd usually starts out in parallel
- `.target` is mainly for "grouping" and "ordering" (see [systemd.target](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/systemd.target.5.en.html))
- In reality, `basic.target` must be activated (along with everything it required and wanted) before reaching `multi-user.target` (which is the default runlevel for a server)

All right, I hope so far I am right.

---

Now, looking `basic.target`:

```
$ sudo cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/basic.target

[Unit]
Description=Basic System
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)

Requires=sysinit.target
After=sysinit.target
Wants=sockets.target timers.target paths.target slices.target
After=sockets.target paths.target slices.target
```

So now my interpretation is:

1. `basic.target` will only be activated **after** `sysinit.target` has succeeded
2. Furthermore, `basic.target` desires to have `sockets.target` and etc to be running
3. The additional `After=` means, okay, please only activate `basic.target` after `sockets.target`, `paths.target`, and `slices.target` are activated. It's okay for `timers.target` to fail.
4. Then why not combine two `After=` into one? Why not use `Require=` instead of `Wants` (except `timers.target`)?

Comment: A very good question, surprisingly there were no answers. I am looking for exact difference between "Requires" and "After". And also the difference between a service is "succeeded" and a service is "activated".

Comment: @stackuser "Requires=" means "Also start the following services if you start me="; "After=" means "If following services are going to start, wait for them to start before starting me="

Answer (score 0):

Your question in point 4 stands out, with the rest serving as context.

> Why not combine two `After=` into one?

There's no technical reason preventing the combination of two `After=` directives. The order of units in `After=`, `Wants=`, and `Requires=` doesn't matter; they can even come from different files (like overrides) and will still be joined into a single set for checking. So, the decision to combine or not can be based on factors like readability and ease of templating.

> Why not use `Require=` instead of `Wants=` (except for `timers.target`)?

to trigger the targets start, but not fail `basic.target` if some of the dependent targets fail.

That's the opposite to `Requires=sysinit.target`, which will trigger `sysinit.target` start and fail the `basic.target` if `sysinit.target` fails.

### Both `Requires=` and `Wants=` will trigger the start of dependent units

(and this will trigger their wants and requires to start, cascading down the tree). The difference lies in what happens if a required service fails to start. If a service is missing or can't be started, all services that `Requires=` that service will also fail to start. However, services that `Wants=` a failed service will still start. For instance, if `paths.target` or `slices.target` fail for any reason in the current configuration, `basic.target` can still be reached with `Wants=`, but not with `Requires=`.

### `After=`, on the other hand, only specifies a start order.

Consider a `some.service` has `After=postres.service` without `Wants=` and `Requires=`, but there is no `postgres.service` in the system. The `some.service` will start as usual, ignoring the missing `postres.service`. If `postres.service` is in system, but fails to start, `some.service` will wait for the attempt of `postres.service` to start, and then start anyway.

Whether `some.service` is enabled or not doesn't matter. If not enabled, when you start it manually, it will start without trying to start `postres.service`.

Adding `Requires=postres.service` or `Wants=postres.service` to `some.service` will cause `postres.service` to also start when starting `some.service` by any means. If `postres.service` is in `Requires=`, its failure to start will also cause `some.service` to fail to start.

If you only specify `Requires=` without `After=`, I'm not entirely sure. My guess is `systemd` will start them simultaneously, and failure of `postres.service` will do nothing.

** there is one case I'm sure about though: if in `some.service` you only specify `Requires=postres.service` without `After=postres.service`, but the `postres.service` is missing from the system, any attempts to start `some.service` will fail.

This is why it’s common to use both `Requires=` and `After=` together when you want to ensure that one service successfully starts before starting another service.